# jQuery iterate through <td> in selected row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to iterate through all the  elements in an table. Actually, I need to iterate through all the columns of a HTML table, to set the "bSearchable" attribute for the datatables  jquery plugin.

I have a variable column number table (based on the value selected in a dropdownlist, I generate a table that has either 12 or 13 columns), so I cannot use "aoColumns" attribute.

I need to return to "aoColumns" a custom javascript array setting for each column "bSearchable" to true or false;

So, I need to add to this vector "bSearchable" : true for the first column and "bSearchable" : false for all the other columns.

I tried something like this:

```
function setSearchable() {
    var result = new Array();
    result.push([{"bSearchable": true}]);
    $('#productsTable tr').eq(1).  // this is where I got stuck
}
```

Comment: Why can you not do this in the `datatables` initialisation?

Answer (score 2):

To find all the `<td>` elements in a given row, use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find).

```
$('#productsTable tr').eq(1).find("td");
```

Or, more specifically, to find all the `<td>` elements that are children (direct descendants) of the row, use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children).

```
$('#productsTable tr').eq(1).children("td");
```

You can use the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) method for iteration, though it doesn't sound like you really need to be looping here at all, since you only care about the number of elements, and not the specific elements.

```
$('#productsTable tr').eq(1).children("td").each(function() {
    results.push([{"bSearchable": false}]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I finally used:

```
 function setSearchable() {
var result = new Array();
result.push({ "bSearchable": true });
var index = 0;
$('#productsTable tbody tr:eq(0) td').each(function () {
    if (index != 0)
        result.push({ "bSearchable": false });
    index++;
});
return result;
}
```

I also accidentally introduced a bug when using

```
result.push([{"bSearchable": true}]);
```

instead of

```
 result.push({"bSearchable": true});
```

I actually pushed distinct vectors instead of pushing values to the initial vector. As a result, the datatable never got the "bSearchable" values for the columns set.